# Laravel redirect after create TXT file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have function that create TXT file. I'm trying to redirect to same page with parameter when it success to create a TXT file.

```
$fileName = "GROUP".$footerExport.".txt";

$headers = [
  'Content-type' => 'text/plain', 
  'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $fileName)
];

return Response::make($output, 200, $headers);
```

I have tried `header` before return also doesn't work. Any other way to redirect when success create TXT file?

```
$url = action('ECFTController@payECFT', ['ClaimPeriod' => $claimPeriod, 'CategoryID' => $CategoryID]);
header('Location: '.$url);

return Response::make($output, 200, $headers);
```

Comment: why not you using ajax for that ?

Comment: how can i using ajax? sorry, i'm not very good in ajax

Answer (score 0):

you can do redirect by return back()->with(['data'])..
for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you creating file with this way

I want to share my way with you

You can create file with `File` facade

Example:

```
$fileName = "GROUP".$footerExport.".txt";

File::put($fileName,'Your contents here');
```

And After that, just redirect to previous route

```
return back();
```

Let me know if this help you or not

Comment: it's work for redirect but i don't want to store the file at server. just save the file at local pc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create and download the text file:

1. If you just want to create file with some content the way provided in above solution is correct i.e.:

   `$fileName = "GROUP".$footerExport.".txt";
   File::put($fileName,'Your contents here');`

and then just use `return redirect()->back()->with('Extra data if required');`

2. If you want to create and also have this file on local machine also then you will have to create, download and redirect back in one process which create some issue, so to solve simple solution is using helper:

   `$filename = 'abc.text';
   Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');`

now here you can save this file name in **session using put** or can send back through **data** and when you redirect **fire an ajax request with filename to download file**.
and simply use download to download your file on your machine i.e.:

```
return response()->download(storage_path($filename));
```

and for deleting file if you don't want to leave this file on server use

```
Storage::delete('filename');
```

Hope this helps.